# How to call a class variable by different names?

Tags: c++, class, substitution

How to call a class variable by different names?

I mean similarly to something like this:

```
class test{
  int values[2];
  #define right values[0] // <- something like this
  #define left values[1]
};

int main(){
  test obj;
  obj.values[1] = 23; // this is the same thing
  obj.left = 23;      // <-'
  int left = 10;      // error, because this is equal to int values[1]=10;
}
```

I want to do something like that but without the global substitution of the words left and right.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: please show real code. The errors in your example just distract from your actual question

Comment: whats wrong about the obvious `int& left() { return values[0]; }` ? Why do you put the two values in a c-array when you actually want to acces them differerntly?

Comment: @user463035818 You can simply swap these to values without altering external pointers/references. I don't think, this is the point here though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use evil macros:

```
#define right values[0]
#define left  values[1]
```

Another idea is to use named constants:

```
const size_t right = 0;
const size_t left  = 1;
/...
int r = values[right];
int l = values[left];
```

Although, IMHO, the better idiom is to use 2 separate variables instead of an array:

```
int right;
int left;
```

You could also use pointers:

```
int * left = &values[1];
int * right = &value[0];
//...
*left = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use references:

```
struct test {
    int values[2];
    int& right = values[0];
    int& left = values[1];
};
```

Note that they are actual members of the class, so they take an unspecified amount of size. In practice this doesn't really matter though, as two references are hardly big.

Comment: It's worth pointing out here that this changes the size of the class; and doesn't just rename variables.

Comment: @UKMonkey Thanks! Added :)

Answer (score 4):

You can just use inline methods which do something similar:

```
class test{
  int values[2];
  int & right() { return values[0]; }
  int const & right() const { return values[0]; }
  int & left() { return values[1]; }
  int const & left() const { return values[1]; }
};
```

or use references:

```
class test{
  int values[2];
  int & right = values[0]; // initialization syntax with C++11 or later. For pre-
  int & left = values[1];  // C++11, these must be initialized in the constructor
};
```

However, with references, given a `const test obj`, `obj.right` and `obj.left` still refer to non-`const` integers, i.e. have type `int &`, not `const int &`. Additionally, these extra references increase the size of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pointers in class named as 'left' and 'right' to point to values[0] and [1] like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int arr[2];
arr[0]=20;
arr[1]=30;
int *x=&arr[0];
int *y=&arr[1];


  cout<<"x is " << *x;
}
```

Comment: that works, but will add 2 pointers to the class unecessarely.

Comment: do u know of any way to do that but without the need of having rwoextra pointer on the class